# Cosmos DB error code 400 while creating a new document

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I've created an Azure Cosmos DB (selecting MongoDB as the language), and while creating a new document through the Azure portal (website) it fails and says:

```
{"code":400,"body":"Command insert failed: document does not contain shard key."}
```

I tried to create the following document through the website:

```
{
    "wordpress_id": "test"
}
```

And this:

```
{
    "id" : "replace_with_new_document_id",
    "wordpress_id": "test"
}
```

`"wordpress_id"` is a `"Shard key"` (or partition key) that I defined when I created the collection. It is also a **Unique key**.

This is what I [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRc1c.png) in the "Scale & Settings" tab.
This is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIsgr.png) I see when I try to create the document.

Am I missing something?

Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Did you try to run the same operation from a Mongo client, for example, [Robomongo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-robomongo)

Comment: Thanks! Creating the collections with this tool did work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing something? Do you know why this is happening?

I also could reproduce this issue if I created a shared collection from Azure portal.

According to the azure [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data#partitioning-and-provisioned-throughput), we could know that we could create the shared collection with **favorite tool,driver, or SDK**.

> With the MongoDB API, you can create a sharded collection through your **favorite tool, driver, or SDK**.

I do a demo with [studio3t](https://studio3t.com/) tool. The Mongo Shell I used

```
db.runCommand( { shardCollection: "databaseName.collectionName", key: { KeyName: "hashed" } } )
```

Run the Mongo Shell from the studio3t

[image]

After that we could create the document from Azure portal correctly.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It does work, although it is very strange that the official Azure portal is not recognised as a favourite tool,driver, or SDK by Microsoft. I used Robomongo for this.

Comment: We identified the issue on the Portal and will be releasing a fix for this scenario.

Comment: @JuliánCalleja The Portal has been fixed and creation is working correctly.