# Sharded collections and MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, sharding

I've created a sharded collection on Cosmos (for use with C# MongoDB driver) through the portal. Created using Data Explorer -> New Collection - Shard Key set at this point.

I've set the shard key to be `partitionId`.

As an example when trying to insert this document into a collection named "data":

```
db.data.insert({partitionId:"test"})
```

I receive the error `Command insert failed: document does not contain shard key.`

Comment: Please edit your question to show your code, where you're trying to insert a document. Also please show how you configured the shard key.

Comment: Another question here suggests not using the portal, but creating it manually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48202411/5405453

Comment: Thanks that reference helped, creating it using Robo3T works fine.

Comment: @cowlinb6 I tried to repro your case and the sharded collection created by the Portal works correctly in my case. Did you input the shard key as just "partitionId" or "/partitionId"? Is this a brand new Mongo account or one you had for some time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

There seem to be issues when creating the sharded collection using the portal. Manually creating the sharded collection should work, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48202411/5405453

**Original:**

From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/):

> The shard key determines the distribution of the collection’s
>   documents among the cluster’s shards. The shard key is either an
>   indexed field or indexed compound fields that exists in every document
>   in the collection.

On creation of the sharded collection, you have provided a key which should be used as shard key. Next if you insert a document it has to contain that key. See [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/#shard-a-collection).

Comment: The collection has a shard key of partitionId and I cannot insert this document:

{ partitionId: "test" }

Comment: @cowlinb6 please *Edit your question* with details; don't add details as comments. Also, what you added here isn't enough detail ; that isn't a proper insert statement, nor does it look like a complete document.

Comment: @nijm There is not enough info in the original question, to provide an answer. Just pointing to official mongodb docs isn't really an answer, especially when we have no details.

Comment: David Makogon thanks for the feedback I've updated the question with more detail.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I agree, however the little information implied to me, there was/is little knowledge of sharding and shard keys. But yes, this is not an actual solution.

Comment: @cowlinb6: do you have an index on that key?